# Haskell input with txt file

Tags: haskell, input

I am working on a program to get the closest prime number by the exponent of 2, this is between an interval.

```
module Main where

import Data.Char
import System.IO
import Control.Monad (liftM)

data PGetal =  G Bool | P Int
instance Show PGetal where
          show (P n) = show n
          show (G False) = "GEEN PRIEMGETAL GEVONDEN"

mPriem::(Int, Int) -> PGetal
mPriem (x,y) | (x > y) = G False
         | (x > 1000000) = G False
         | (y > 1000000) = G False
         | (null (getAllPriem(x,y))) = G False
         | otherwise = P (kleinsteVerschilF(getAllPriem(x,y),1000000,1))


kleinsteVerschilF:: ([Int], Int , Int) -> Int
kleinsteVerschilF ([],_, priemGetal) = priemGetal
kleinsteVerschilF (priem1:priemcss, kleinsteVerschil,priemGetal)=
                                        if(kleinsteVerschil <= kleinsteVerschilMetLijst (priem1,(getMachtenVanTwee(0)),1000000))then kleinsteVerschilF(priemcss, kleinsteVerschil,priemGetal)
                                                                                                                          else kleinsteVerschilF (priemcss,kleinsteVerschilMetLijst(priem1,(getMachtenVanTwee(0)),1000000), priem1)



kleinsteVerschilMetLijst :: (Int,[Int],Int) -> Int
kleinsteVerschilMetLijst ( _,[],kleinsteVerschil) = kleinsteVerschil
kleinsteVerschilMetLijst (x,tweeMachten1:tweeMachtencss,kleinsteverschil)=
                         if((abs(x-tweeMachten1)) < kleinsteverschil)
                                                  then kleinsteVerschilMetLijst(x,tweeMachtencss, (abs(x-tweeMachten1)))
                                                  else kleinsteVerschilMetLijst(x,tweeMachtencss, kleinsteverschil)


getAllPriem :: (Int, Int) ->[Int]
getAllPriem (x,y) = filter isPriem [x..y]


getMachtenVanTwee ::(Int) -> [Int]
getMachtenVanTwee (macht)
                  |(functieMachtTwee(macht)< 1000000) = (functieMachtTwee(macht)) : (getMachtenVanTwee ((macht+1)))
                  | otherwise = []

functieMachtTwee:: (Int) -> Int
functieMachtTwee (x) = 2^x


isPriem n = (aantalDelers n)==2

aantalDelers n = telAantalDelersVanaf n 1
telAantalDelersVanaf n kandidaatDeler
  | n == kandidaatDeler       = 1
  | mod n kandidaatDeler == 0
      = 1 + telAantalDelersVanaf n (kandidaatDeler+1)
  | otherwise
      = telAantalDelersVanaf n (kandidaatDeler+1)

aantalDelers2 getal = telDelers getal 1 0
  where telDelers n kandidaat teller
          | n == kandidaat = 1+teller
          | mod n kandidaat == 0
              = telDelers n (kandidaat+1) (teller+1)
          | otherwise
              = telDelers n (kandidaat+1) teller

transform :: [String] -> [PGetal]
transform [] = []
transform (cs:css) =
  let (a : b: _ ) = words cs
     in (mPriem ((read(a)),(read(b))): transform css)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- read `liftM` getLine :: IO Int
  lss <- lines `liftM` getContents

  let cases = take n lss
  let vs = (transform (lss))

  putStr $ unlines $ map show vs
```

When I use the mPriem function, it works fine.
But it needs to work with an input txt file, so I made a .exe file with the ghc command. I also added this .txt file in the folder.

```
10
1 1
1 3
1 100
200 250
14 16
5 10
20 31
16 50
100 120
5200 7341
```

When I use in command line this command, it does nothing. There is no output. I can't CTRL+C to stop the program, so I think it crashes. But I don't know what's wrong.

```
type invoer.txt | programma.exe
```

Comment: are you sure you should use `type`? On Linux the `type` command means: *"indicate how a command would be interpreted"*. What about I/O redirect: `programma.exe < invoer.txt` or `cat invoer.txt | programma.exe`?

Comment: I'm using windows, i thought i needed to use type.
The commands you said did the same, it get stuck.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `type invoer.txt`? After all this is what you feed `programma.exe`...

Comment: With the "type invoer.txt", I get my txt file in my command screen.

Comment: Well if I run the program with `runhaskell file.hs < input`, I get output: `GEEN PRIEMGETAL GEVONDEN 2 2 241 GEEN PRIEMGETAL GEVONDEN 5 31 17 113 7333` (removed new lines). But it it taking some time (approx 20 seconds). I think it is not very efficient to calculate all *delers* first: from the moment you found another one, you can safely assume it is not a prime number.

Comment: I get a similar thing from the command line inside ghci; the last input, `5200 7341` takes a while. But the rest works fast.

Comment: ...sorry,  not able to reproduce. `type invoer.txt | programma.exe` works fine on my machine. (Compiled using GHC version 7.6.3). On the bright side, it seems that the problem is not with your Haskell code.

Comment: Well most shells allow IO redirection, so `programma.exe < invoer.txt` should do the trick; unless something went wrong when compiling to `programma.txt`. You probably can also run it with the `runhaskell` interpreter.

Comment: Furthermore when looking to the source code (since I'm a Belgian, my native language is *Dutch*), I think this code is "overdesigned".

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I find it strange it don't work with me, I'm running the .exe file now for around 10minutes and I get no return. So it's weird, I'am already very happy it works with you guys.

I'am new  to haskell, so I'am trying to make some random excerses. Because I'm new to this, I used functions and variables in my native language, wherefor my apologies. Next time, I have a problem, I will translate it all.

I will look and try to make my problem more efficient.

Comment: @user3464048: If you can explain what you aim to do with `kleinsteVerschil...` we can perhaps improve the quality of the program.

Comment: @user3464048: furthermore what happens if you use I/O redirection: `./programma.exe < invoer.txt` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Your program works, but is not that efficient and personally I find it not that elegant (sorry :S) because you introduce a lot of "noise". As a result it takes a lot of time before output is written.

If I understand the problem statement correctly, each line (except the first), contains two integers, and you need to count the amount of prime numbers between these two numbers (bounds inclusive?)

First of all, you can do this more elegantly by defining a function: `cPrime :: Int -> Int -> Int` that takes as input the two numbers and returns the amount of prime numbers:

```
cPrime :: Int -> Int -> Int
cPrime a b = count $ filter isPrime [a .. b]
```

You can improve performance by improving your prime checking algorithm. First of all, you do not need to check whether `1` is a divisor, since `1` is always a divisor. Furthermore, you can prove mathematically that there is no divisor greater than *sqrt(n)* (except for *n*) that divides *n*; unless there is another divider that is smaller than *sqrt(n)*. So that means that you can simply enumerate all numbers between `2` and `sqrt n` and from the moment one of these is a divisor, you can stop: you have proven the number is not prime:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n = all ((0 /=) . mod n) (2:[3,5..m])
    where m = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

Now I'm not sure what you aim to do with `kleinsteVerschilF`.